# does akka queue support unit of order, which is available in weblogic jms queue

Tags: jms, weblogic, akka, sequential

we are investigating porting an application from weblogic to use akka. the application utilize  the unit of order feature offered by weblogic jms queue to make sure messages for the same order (identified by order id) are processed by the message driven bean sequentially.
the questions: does AKKA support this feature? what is the best way to implement this if AKKA does not have it off the shelf?

Answer (score 1):

An Akka Actor processes its messages serially, so just send the messages that needs serial execution to the same Actor and you'll be fine.

Comment: in my case, that means i need to create an actor for each order. Because the application processes huge number of orders per day, and orders could be long running orders, the application needs to create and manage huge number of actors too. I am skeptical this would be practical in production.

Comment: Why would you need to create one actor per order? You just need to make sure that the same order number goes to the same actor – use a Consistent Hashing Router (see Routing section of Akka documentation)

Comment: suppose i use consistent hashing router to route messages(e.g. M1, M2, M3) for order ORD1 to a certain actor A1. if A1 is processing M1, i am not sure how to make A1 not to processing M2 or M3 until finishing processing M1.

Comment: An Actor can only process one message at a time.